# How to change the LabelText color of a UIButton?

Tags: ipad, ios4, uibutton

Hi i am creating a UIButton programatically and I am trying to change the text color of the button's textLabel to orange. I've tried both lines below but they aren't working. Can someone tell me how to do this properly.

```
[myButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

and,

```
myButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Comment: Both code snippets are correct and should work. Try setting a breakpoint in the debugger on this line of code and check that `myButton` is the button you expect (and is not nil).

Comment: The problem here is that a UIButton's titleLabel is read only, though its properties are not. That's why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Why should that make the code not work? Just tested, works fine both in the simulator and on the device (iOS 4.3.3 / Xcode 4.0.2).

Comment: That said, your answer is of course correct – as soon as the state changes, the changes to the label will be gone (and if the button isn't on screen yet, they likely won't be visible at all). However, it is possible to change the color of the button's label in its current state using these methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state` instead:

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The problem here is that a UIButton's titleLabel is read only, though its properties are not. That's why your seemingly correct code doesn't work.